# Facebook like button triggering security warning on webpages

Tags: html, facebook

I have some pages on my site that I put the simple facebook like buttons on as seen in the code below.

```
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1"></script>
<fb:like href="" layout="button_count" show_faces="false" width="200" action="recommend" font="arial"></fb:like>
```

Recently, perhaps in the past few days this seems to have started, when visit those pages in IE9, the browser pops up a warning saying "only secure content is displayed" with a button saying show all content.  These pages are not secure and there is no reason for them to be, so i am not sure why it is telling me this.

Is there a way i can make the button not trigger this warning?  The warning only seems to happen in IE9, the pages load just fine in safari, firefox, and even IE9 in compatibility mode from my testing.  Also i have run across other sites that use the same button that show the same behavior, so I am guessing it might be something on facebooks end?

**edit:** I have tried looking at the site again from my home system on IE9 and it seemed to not complain about security to me.  This makes me think it has something to do with my work browsers security levels.  The question still remains about why it would bring up any security issues at all,  the pages are all http:// pages, no 's'.  Perhaps something in facebook's script is doing something secure?

**edit2:** I found the problem, it was the IE security option for display mixed contents.  It was set to prompt, setting it to enabled made the error go away.  I dont like that solution, but i have a feeling that the facebook script does some secure stuff at some point and that is what is bothering IE9.

Comment: Mixed content is mixed content. Either your site or facebook is using https. Find out where the problem is, and change it. Just changing security settings isn't a good solution, and will make your users think their facebook page is getting hacked =D

Comment: Yeah it is definatly not my site,  i can comment out the facebook bit and it works perfect.  Unfortunatly for me, I do not run facebook so i can only hope at some point they make their script not run secure.

Answer (score 1):

Just change your `<script>` tag to the `https:` URL:

```
<script src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Is it safe to assume your website is running `HTTPS`? is so, make sure you include the facebook connect script from `HTTPS` as well. e.g.

```
<script src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1"></script>
```

Comment: I will try making that change when i get back to work and can push it out,  I was tempted to try that, but for whatever reason i told myself there was no reason doing that will work.  We shall see in the morning.

Comment: @andykrynn: It's always the "nah, it's not that" answer that's usually the winner. ;-)

Comment: Well i solved the problem,  unfortunately it was not the https change in the script address.  The solution was to change the IE security option to enabled for the "display mixed contents".  Unfortunately i do not like this for two reasons, first, i like the idea that the browser would warn me about that kind of thing, and second, i cannot force this behavior on the readers of the site. It seems that short of getting facebook to change their script, this is not going to be solvable.

Comment: If you changed the Facebook scripts to `https` and you're still getting that warning, you're probably still loading resources from non-secure URLs. Check all your images, other javascripts, even CSS that's loaded from an absolute domain.

Answer (score 0):

There is a reported bug now about this, please vote at http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=18627

Answer (score 0):

the updated link for the bug is https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/174276242655775